# Fundamental group of 7-gon with labelling scheme $abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I want to calculate the fundamental group of of a $7$-gon with labelling scheme $abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$. I will call the quotient space $X$ with reference point $x_0$. This is what I tried:

If you have the book topology of Munkres, Theorem 74.2 says that this fundamental group should be isomorphic to the quotient of the free group on the generators $a$ and $b$ by the least normal subgroup containing the element $aba^3b^{-1}a^{-1}$. So if $G_1=\langle a\rangle$ and $G_2=\langle b\rangle$ and $N$ is this least normal subgroup containing $aba^3b^{-1}a^{-1}$, then $\pi_1(X,x_0)=(G_1 *G_2)/N$. Now theorem 68.7 of the same book says that if you have two groups $H_1$ and $H_1$ and two normal subgroups $M_1\subset H_1$ and $M_2\subset H_2$ and suppose $M$ is the least normal subgroup of $H_1*H_2$ containing both $M_1$ and $M_2$ then we have the isomorphism $(H_1*H_2)/M\cong H_1/M_1*H_2/M_2$.

In my case, I have a normal subgroup $N$ of $G_1*G_2$ which contains the element $aba^3b^{-1}a^{-1}$. I see that this element is a conjugate: $(ab)a^3(ab)^{-1}$. So $a^3\in N$ and we must have that $N_1$ is the least normal subgroup of $G_1$ containing the element $a^3$, that is $N_1=\langle a^3\rangle$. I cannot find a normal subgroup $N_2$ of $G_2$ which is contained in $N$ except for the trivial group. So I think that $\pi_1(X,x_0)\cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

I am not sure whether this is correct. In particular, I am not sure whether $N_2$ is the trivial normal subgroup of $G_2$. Can you help me at this point? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the n-gon? you should see that two of the $a$s cancel and both of the $b$s cancel (that is you can 'zip' them together). So you should be left with just a triangle with labelling scheme $aaa$. This is also easy to see algebraically because labelling schemes are invariant under cyclic permutation.

Comment: @DanielRust So the fundamental group should be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? What went wrong in my calculation then?

Comment: I don't have a copy of Munkres handy so I can't see the quoted theorem, but there must be some conditions you've not taken into account. For instance the square with labelling scheme $aa^{-1}bb^{-1}$ is homeomorphic to a sphere which has trivial fundamental group, but it appears that your method would conclude that its fundamental group was $\langle a, b \mid aa^{-1}bb^{-1}\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is a subtely when calculating the fundamental group of an $n$-gon with labelling scheme using the Van Kampen theorem in that you should make sure that the punctured space doesn't have 'degenerate' loops. That is, you want each of the symbols representing edges to actually give a distinct circle in the eventual wedge you get from deformation retracting the punctured $n$-gon onto the 'boundary'. In my above example this does not happen because the vertices at either end of the $a$ and $b$ edges are not identified.

Comment: @DanielRust is spot on, you've forgotten this condition from the statement of the theorem: "If $\pi$ maps all the vertices of $P$ to a single point $x_0$ of $X$ [...]".

Comment: @DanielRust Thank you very much! I totally forgot that condition. This was an exercise in Munkres and it says that this fundamental group must be a free product of two cyclic groups. I thought it should be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ because I thought I should calculate only the fundamental group of a 3-gon with labelling scheme $aaa$

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So I cannot use this theorem for the 7-gon with labelling scheme $abaaab^{-1}a^{-1}$, but if you draw this then this space should be homotopy equivalent to the 3-gon with the labelling scheme $aaa$ because of the comment of DanielRust. On this 3-gon I can use this theorem, which states that the fundamental group should be $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, because we have only one generator $a$ and we must divide by the normal subgroup containing $a^3$. In the book this is an exercise which states that the fundamental group should be the free product of two cyclic groups. What went wrong?

Comment: Ha, I think I have to take back the above comments. I was too quick to assume that you can just forget about the $a$ and $a^{-1}$ which appear next to each other, but this isn't the case because they are also identified with other edges in the $n$-gon so they can't just 'zip up' and disappear. The condition @NajibIdrissi mentioned **is** satisfied by your labeling scheme and so you can apply the theorem, in which case your calculation is correct! Apologies for leading you astray!

Comment: @DanielRust Thanks, I now understand where I went wrong, indeed, you can't just forget about the $a$ and $a^{-1}$ because there are other edges with that label. Thank you very much for your time :)